# capybara + selenium + rspec + element not found

Tags: selenium, ruby-on-rails-3.2, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I m using capybara + selenium + rspec to test my application. I have a page, none of whose elements are manipulated by ajax or javascript(hide/show/toggle). When ever i try to submit the form on the page using

```
click_button 'Save'
```

it gives me an error stating element not found. i used 'save_and_open_page' to view the html contents and everything looks fine. the page needs to be scrolled down the access the button. Just for curiosity, i changed the button position so that i dont need to scroll the page and can directly access the button when the page is loaded. In the later case, my capybara spec runs fine. I m not able to derive the root of the problem behind this weird behavior of capybara. The issue is, in most of my views, my submit buttons can be accessed after scrolling the page. How do i avoid the above problem?

the gem versions are

```
capybara 2.1.0
selenium 0.2.10
selenium-client 1.2.18
selenium-webdriver 2.33.0
```

the capybara code

```
fill_in 'user_name', :with => 'Abc Xyz'
fill_in 'user_phone', :with => '58743653'
fill_in 'user_password', :with => 'prasad'
fill_in 'user_password_confirmation', :with => 'prasad'
fill_in 'user_designation', :with => 'Programmer'
page.execute_script "window.scroll(0,10000)"
#find_by_id('save_user').native.send_key(:enter)
sleep 20
page.execute_script("$('form.of-setup').submit()") #current hack to make it work
#click_button 'save my profile'
current_url.include?("registrations/terms/#{@user.invitation_token}").should == true
```

if i uncomment the 'save my profile' button, it gives error as

```
Failure/Error: click_button 'save my profile'
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
Unable to find button "save my profile"
```

and if i uncomment the 'send key' line, it gives error as

```
Failure/Error: find_by_id('save_user').native.send_key(:enter)
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
Unable to find id "save_user"
```

the haml code is as

```
...# additional view code
.optional-area
  .container
    .row
      .span2
        &nbsp;
      .span14
        %fieldset
          = f.text_field :designation, :help => 'Type a job title', :placeholder => "(optional; like Senior Design Engineer)", :label => "Title"
          = f.text_area :street, :rows => "2", :help => "Type the company's street number and name", :placeholder => "(optional; like 1111)", :label => "Street Address"
          = f.text_field :city, :help => 'Type a city name', :placeholder => "(optional; like San Jose)"
          = f.text_field :state, :help => 'Type a stae or province name or abbreviation', :placeholder => "(optional; like CA)", :label => "State/Province"
          = f.text_field :postal_code, :help => 'Type a postal code', :placeholder => "(optional; like 95131)"
    .row
      .span12.offset4
        = f.submit "save my profile", :class => "btn primary verylarge toUpperCase", :disable_with => "SAVE MY PROFILE", :id => 'save_user'
        = link_to 'cancel', root_path, :class => "cancel-link of-link of-cancel toUpperCase quickhelp", 'data-placement' => "above", :title => "Abandon the action"
...#additional view code
```

Comment: can you drop your html ? It may a frame problem or name.

Comment: @e1che added errors in details. added capybara code n haml view code too. if i move the submit button right before the designation text field so that its visible when page is loaded, the code works fine without the hack.

Comment: Is "save my profile" button enabled always or only after you fill in fields?

Comment: Try using the button id, save_user. Or do something like page.find("#save_user").click.

Comment: tried it. it doesnt work. Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css "#save_user"

Comment: Do you see this button by your eyes while are tests are running? Also try to invoke [`html` method](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Session#html-instance_method) to inspect whether this button is really situated in HTML.